# Sort numbers in array by digits (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, numbers, digit

I need a PHP script which would sort an array of numbers by first digit, then by second digit, and so on.

For example, an array:

```
$arr = array(1, 94, 4, 925, 401, 277, 255);
```

should result in a sort like this:

1, 
255, 
277, 
4, 
401,
925, 
94

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sort it as strings, by passing `SORT_STRING` to the [`sort()`](http://php.net/sort) function:

```
sort( $arr, SORT_STRING);
```

This [outputs](http://viper-7.com/m2Xpc1):

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 255
    [2] => 277
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 401
    [5] => 925
    [6] => 94
)
```

Comment: Thanks! Never thought of that.

Answer (score 3):

```
sort($arr, SORT_STRING);
```

See the manual page for sort:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php

Answer (score 0):

Syntax

bool sort ( array &$array [, int $sort_flags = SORT_REGULAR ] )
This function sorts an array. Elements will be arranged from lowest to highest when this function has completed.

```
$arr = array(1, 94, 4, 925, 401, 277, 255);

sort( $arr, SORT_STRING);

var_dump($arr);
```

The above poster used this link. Here is an example using your code